# Do these new maps exist in GTA V for PS3?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I'm wondering if there are these kind of racing maps in GTA V for PS3 since I ordered it.

[image]

I don't mean exactly like this one but like these objects.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

No. These objects were added to GTA Online in the Cunning Stunts update, however updates stopped being released on PS3 and Xbox 360 before the Freemode Events update, which was before Cunning Stunts.